# Formulas formato condicional excel

Tags: excel

Alguien sabe como funciona el formato condicional en excel, me refiero de manera interna:
Tengo los siguientes datos:

[image: Datos Excel]

Y en el formato condicional dice:
[image: Formato Condicional]

Como calcula excel los valores porcentuales para poder dar el color al indicador?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la formula

(ValorCalcular - Minimo)/(Maximo - Minimo)

Donde minimo = 199,437, maximo = 552,526, valor a calcular = valores de X

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo más fácil sin complicarse con formulas es cambiar el tipo "porcentaje" a "número" y luego en valores colocar los rangos que se quieran dependiendo los datos.

[image]